# Обмен данными между вкладками с помощью LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, localstorage

Пользователь открывает сайт. начинает выполняться скрипт, который с определенным интервалом проверяет метку времени в `localStorage`. Если прошло определенное количество времени (`oldDate - currentDate > pullDelay`), то скрипт меняет метку времени на текущую.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <script>
        var pullDelay = 20000;   
        setInterval(function () {
            var date = localStorage.date;  
            if (date) {    
                var currentDate = new Date();    
                var oldDate = new Date(date);    
                var diff = currentDate.getTime() - oldDate.getTime();
                if (diff < pullDelay) {
                    console.log("Данные свежие");
                } else {
                    console.log("Данные устарели");
                    localStorage.date = currentDate;
                }
                console.log("oldDate:" + oldDate.getMinutes() + ":" + oldDate.getSeconds());
                console.log("currentDate:" + currentDate.getMinutes() + ":" + currentDate.getSeconds());
            } else {
                localStorage.date = new Date();
            }
        }, pullDelay);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Ожидалось следующее поведение, открываем первую вкладку, скрипт устанавливает метку времени, и затем каждый раз пишет, что данные устарели и изменяет метку времени. А если открыть вторую вкладку (предполагается, что в момент открытия второй вкладки данные будут свежие), то скрипт всегда будет выводить, что данные свежие.

Текущее поведение:

Первая вкладка работает как и предполагалось, а вот вторая лишь в первый раз пишет, что данные свежие, а затем постоянно пишет, что данные устарели, и метка времени всегда имеет значение, которое это вкладка и устанавливает. То есть когда первая вкладка устанавливает новое значение метки времени, вторая его не видит и выдает значение, которое сама ранее и установила.

Логи:

1-я вкладка:

```
Данные устарели
oldDate:49:29
currentDate:49:49

Данные устарели
oldDate:49:49
currentDate:50:9

Данные устарели
oldDate:50:9
currentDate:50:29
```

2-я вкладка:

```
Данные устарели
oldDate:49:29
currentDate:49:53

Данные устарели
oldDate:49:53
currentDate:50:13

Данные устарели
oldDate:50:13
currentDate:50:33
```

Comment: Работайте с событиями, забудьте про интервалы

Comment: В [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/teLvwzo8/) код работает так, как ожидалось.

Answer (score 2):

У localStorage есть событие **onstorage**

[Пример](http://html5demos.com/storage-events)

Answer (score 1):

Код проверил, работает так же, как и ожидалось. Проблема где-то в другом месте.

`localStorage` - это одно из средств слежения за пользователями в инете. Поэтому некоторые плагины к браузеру или антивирусы могут пытаться его "резать". Попробуйте отключить их.

Также не забудьте проверить базовые вещи: на одном ли домене открыты обе вкладки - и не используете ли вы режим инкогнито-или-как-он-там-называется-в-вашем-браузере.

Comment: Так если бы `localStorage` был "зарезан" или не было бы взаимодействия между вкладками (инкогнито, домен и прочее), то во второй вкладке не было бы _oldDate:49:29_.

Comment: Браузер IE, и необходима совместимость с IE8(
Запускал с помощью VIsual Studio, домен один и тот же был, скорей всего я что-то не учел

Answer (score 0):

В [этой статье](https://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/31514/) на примере музыки ВКонтакте рассматривается решение практически Вашего случая.

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/91704)

Comment: По ссылка ОГРОМНАЯ статья - ну не копипастить же её сюда?

Comment: Если ссылка станет неактивной, ваш ответ перестанет быть актуальным. Обычно рекомендуется написать ключевые моменты из ссылки, которые будут решением вопроса автора.